# R code in package vignette cannot run on CRAN for security reasons. How to manage such vignette?

Tags: r, cran, vignette, r-package

An R package communicates with a commercial data base using a private
user_name and password to establish connection.
In the package_vignette.Rmd file there is a chunk of code:

````
```{r, eval = TRUE}
# set user_name and password from user's configuration file
set_connection(file = "/home/user001/connection.config")

# ask data base for all metrics it has
my_data <- get_all_metrics()

# display names of fetched metrics
head(my_data$name)
```
````

I do not have the rights to provide actual user_name and password to CRAN,
so I can not supply genuine 'connection.config' file with the package.
So, of course, this code fragment leads to Error during CRAN checks.

I know two ways to get around CRAN check:

1. Use knitr option: `eval = FALSE`.
2. Make [static vignette with help of the R.rsp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.rsp/vignettes/R_packages-Static_PDF_and_HTML_vignettes.pdf) package.

The first way is too time-consuming, because there are a lot of chunks,
and I rewrite/rebuild the vignette often.
The second way is better for me. But may be there is a better pattern how to support such vignette? For example, in the package's tests I use `testthat::skip_on_cran()` to avoid CRAN checks.

Comment: include sample data in your package, e.g.  fetch_sample_all_metrics(), with non sensitive/anonymized data, and use it in your vignette

Comment: You can set all chunks to `eval=F` by calling `knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval=F)` inside the first chunk.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is just to include the data with your package. Either the dummy data set in:

- the `data` directory. This would allow users to easily access it.
- or in `inst/extdata`. Users can can access this file, but it's a bit more hidden. You would find the location using `system.file(package="my_pkg")`

In the vignette you would have something

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
data(example_data, package="my_pkg")
my_data = example_data
```

```{r, eval = FALSE}
# set user_name and password from user's configuration file
set_connection(file = "/home/user001/connection.config")

# ask data base for all metrics it has
my_data <- get_all_metrics()
```
````

Answer (score 1):

`testthat::skip_on_cran` just checks a system variable

```
> testthat::skip_on_cran
function () 
{
    if (identical(Sys.getenv("NOT_CRAN"), "true")) {
        return(invisible(TRUE))
    }
    skip("On CRAN")
}
<environment: namespace:testthat>
```

From what I gather, this is set by `testthat` or `devtools`. Thus, you could use

```
eval = identical(Sys.getenv("NOT_CRAN"), "true")
```

in the chunk option and load `testthat` or `devtools` in one of the first chunks. Otherwise, you can use a similar mechanism on your site and assign a similar system variable and check if it is `"true"`. E.g., use `Sys.setenv("IS_MY_COMP", "true")`). Then put a `Sys.setenv` call in your `.Rprofile` file if you use R studio or in your `R_HOME/Rprofile.site` file. See `help("Startup")` for information on the later option.

Alternatively, you can check if `"/home/user001/connection.config"` exists with

```
eval = file.exists("/home/user001/connection.config")
```

in the chunk option.